# Преобразовать результат совпадений регулярки в экземпляр класса

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, linq

Есть класс `Product`. В нем содержится массив `Event`.

```
List<Product> listpProducts = new List<Product>();
```

Я хочу результат совпадений регулярки преобразовать сразу в `Event`. Сейчас я создаю буферный список, который потом добавляю в `listpProducts[i].events.Add()`, что не есть комильфо.

```
listpProducts[i].events = Regex.Matches(html,pattern).Cast<Match>();  // Вот тут что нужно добавить?

class Product
{
    public List<Event> collection { get; set; }
}
class Event
{
    public string events { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если свойства называются так, как в вопросе, то:

```
listpProducts[i].collection = Regex.Matches(html,pattern)
                               .Cast<Match>()
                               .Select(m => new Events { events = m.Value })
                               .ToList();
```

или, если список уже создан:

```
listpProducts[i].collection.AddRange(Regex.Matches(html,pattern)
                                      .Cast<Match>()
                                      .Select(m => new Events { events = m.Value }));
```